# Close a GUI window from button in AutoHotKey GUI window not working

Tags: user-interface, autohotkey

I have the [AutoHotKey EnterPad Keyboard/Pad with 120 Programmable Keys](http://cedeq.com/enterpad/en/autohotkey)

[image]

It works by sending a **Hotkey press** for each key to an AutoHotKey script which has a `Label function` for each key named `001` through `120`

Below is my AHK Label function called when key `115` is pressed.

My code allows me to select rows in any Windows Listview component and it will show a popup GUI window with a textbox filled in with the data from the selected rows with each column separated with a `TAB` space.  I can then copy or save it or view it whatever I like.

```
;---------------------------------------------------------------------115-----
; Copy Selected Windows Listview Items to Tab Spaced Text - Show popup Window Gui
; https://superuser.com/questions/814831/copy-to-clipboard-from-table-list-in-a-program-on-windows
115:
    Gui, SelectedListRowsTextGui:Destroy
    MouseGetPos, , , , ListView_hwnd, 2     ;2 means return HWND
    ControlGet, selected_row_text, List, Selected, , ahk_id %ListView_hwnd%
    Gui, SelectedListRowsTextGui: +ToolWindow +AlwaysOnTop -Caption
    Gui, SelectedListRowsTextGui:Add, Edit, vUnused_variable x11 y15 w950 h66, %selected_row_text%
    Gui, SelectedListRowsTextGui:Add, Button, x62 y84 w140 h30 +Center, Close
    Gui, SelectedListRowsTextGui:Show, ,
    return

    ButtonClose:
    Gui, SelectedListRowsTextGui:Destroy
    return

Return
```

### Problem

My issue is that once the popup window is opened from my AHK GUI, my `CloseButton` label dose not get called when I click the close button.

I realize it likely has something to do with it being nested under the key 115s label function. How can I best achieve the desired result?

I tried moving the `CloseButton` label outside of the `115 label` however it still is not called from the GUI's `Close` button click.

You can see I have named the GUI `SelectedListRowsTextGui` this is to allow this Enterpad.ahk script to contain many GUI windows for different actions it will perform.

---

Preview of the GUI window this script creates when listview items are selected and this Label function is called:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got it now....

Since my GUI is named `SelectedListRowsTextGui` I had to add that name in front of my `CloseButton` label name so it is now `SelectedListRowsTextGuiButtonClose` and works great